# Validate numbers encoded by user

Tags: excel

I need to be sure user encode valid numbers in my Excel sheet.

Example of valid numbers:

- 1
- 1,2

Example of invalid numbers

- 1.2

At first, I think of using `Data Validation` allow `Decimal` which block invalid numbers.

The problem with that is that when user encode `3` it is displayed as `3,0` which I prefer not.

So I would like to avoid user to enter alphanumeric values or bad numbers (like `1.2`)

Any alternative/trick?

Thanks.

Comment: "*The problem with that is that when user encode 3 it is displayed as 3,0*" I can't reproduce this. Isn't this just a question of number format?

Comment: You are right: I forgot I had formatted my cells (Number with decimal places: 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting ColumnA, DATA > Data Tools - Data Validation, Settings, Allow: Custom, Formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(A1)
```